# Prevent restarting GNOME Shell from logging me out

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, logout, 18.10

Before upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10, Alt+F2 and then `r` would restart GNOME Shell but would not log out my user, which was nice as my applications would stay open.

After the upgrade, `gnome-shell --replace` and the `r` command cause me to be logged out, as if I had *killed* `gnome-shell`, or `killall -u $USER`.

Can I restore the previous behaviour where the DE was replaced seamlessly without closing my applications?

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Comment: Do  you run Xorg or Wayland?

Comment: Sorry, but Pop!_OS is off-topic here.

Comment: Hmm, broken Gnome restart on Wayland is "normal" - https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/01/26/bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-to-use-xorg-by-default but on Xorg its not..

Comment: @pomsky but that has nothing to do with this, it's just xorg/wayland, and even unmodified mainline Ubuntu doesn't use wayland by default

Comment: @KuriboKutsu this is very interesting, that's how it was in 18.04 and on my MATE systems, just not my GNOME one

Comment: @pomsky this is not an Pop!_OS question, it is an Ubuntu GNOME question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been fixed, so that the previous behaviour of restarting in-place is restored.